# How to install python_abi package through conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I try to install the python_abi package through conda, I get the following error.

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- python_abi

Current channels:

 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
 - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

   https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Comment: @merv When I used conda install python_abi (trust me, I had typed python_abi), I got the above error but I resolved it by using the solution given below. But while posting this question I used the error message for a different package and erroneously replaced the package name with python-abi instead of python_abi. Thank you for bringing it to my notice.

Comment: Okay, retracted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the python_abi package through conda, run one of the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python_abi
conda install -c conda-forge/label/broken python_abi
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 python_abi
```

Comment: One shouldn’t use the latter two unless one knows what one is doing. These suggested commands are automatically generated by Anaconda Cloud, which simply generates this for all labels. The `broken` label is used by Conda Forge to mark bad builds; the `cfYYYYMM` labels are used to tag a specific state of the Conda Forge build stack.